# MySQL - Limit by bottom (X) percent of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-limit

Here's my table structure:

```
+-------+--------+----------+
| item  | price  | quantity |
+-------+--------+----------+
| 22452 | 579150 |        4 |
| 34664 | 334425 |        7 |
| 32249 | 204750 |        3 |
| 39970 |  97500 |        5 |
| 36907 | 116415 |        6 |
|  4338 | 207451 |       17 |
| 23425 | 388050 |        4 |
| 23427 | 532350 |       14 |
| 76080 | 180000 |        6 |
| 76076 | 400000 |        4 |
+-------+--------+----------+
```

Item is not unique and there could be anywhere from 1 to a few thousand rows for each item, so I'm grouping by item for the results. My current query is the following:

```
SELECT  item AS id,
        COUNT(item) as total,
        ROUND(AVG(price/quantity)) AS mean,
        ROUND(MIN(price/quantity)) AS cheapest
FROM `data`
GROUP BY item;
```

In addition to these 4 results, I would like to calculate the average price of the bottom 15% of rows of the `(price/quantity)` value (not < 0.15*MAX(price/quantity) but 0.15*total, ordered by (price/quantity) ASC). The solution I thought of involved temporary tables using the count of that item as the limiter, but I'd highly prefer it to be a single query if possible. I'm sure I'll need a subquery in here, but I'm unsure of how to go about getting the count for that particular item and then limiting by 15% of that result.

### UPDATE WITH ANSWER FROM BELOW

Using @GordonLinoff answer below got me basically all the way there. I did run into two issues, however. The biggest one was the @rn variable wasn't resetting, which was causing it to keep increment and subsequently only the first row of the items was getting included. The second was any item where 15% of the number of times it appears in the table is < 1, NULL was being returned. The corrections were minor and I've included the final query I used below:

```
SELECT item AS id,
       COUNT(item) as total,
       ROUND(AVG(price/quantity)) AS mean,
       ROUND(MIN(price/quantity)) AS cheapest,
       ROUND(avg(case when rn <= IF(cnt * 0.15 < 1, cnt, cnt * 0.15) then price/quantity end)) as Cheapest15Percent 
FROM
    (SELECT d.*, cnt, IF(@item = d.item, @rn := @rn + 1, if(@item := d.item, @rn := 1, 1)) as rn
    FROM `data` d LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT item, COUNT(*) cnt FROM `udata` GROUP BY item) di
    ON d.item = di.item CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT @rn := 0, @item := -1) vars
    ORDER BY d.item, d.price/d.quantity) d
GROUP BY d.item;
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Possible Dupe?  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20260/select-top-in-mysql

Comment: Do you want this per item?  Or for the table after the aggregation?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Per item. I'm wanting to get the number of times item appears in "data". If Item 1234 appears 100 times, I want to sort that item by (price/quantity) ASC and then get the average of (price/quantity) for the top 15 rows (100*0.15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that you want the average of the cheapest 15% for each item.

The following query enumerates the rows for each item and gets the total rows:

```
  select d.*, cnt,
         if(@item = item, @rn := @rn + 1, if(@item := item, 1, 1)) as rn
  from `data` d left join
       (select item, count(*) cnt
        from data
        group by item
       ) di
       on d.item = di.item cross join
       (select @rn := 0, @item := -1) vars
  order by item, price/quantity;
```

You can then basically plug this into your query and do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT item AS id,
       COUNT(item) as total,
       ROUND(AVG(price/quantity)) AS mean,
       ROUND(MIN(price/quantity)) AS cheapest,
       avg(case when rn <= cnt * 0.15 then price/quantity end) as Cheapest15Percent
FROM (select d.*, cnt,
             if(@item = item, @rn := @rn + 1, if(@item := item, 1, 1)) as rn
      from `data` d left join
           (select item, count(*) cnt
            from data
            group by item
           ) di
           on d.item = di.item cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @item := -1) vars
      order by item, price/quantity
     ) d
GROUP BY item;
```

Comment: The query didn't run as is. I assumed "from dat" should have been "from `data`" I also had to label the top most columns. (d.item, d.price, etc) 

The results were close. But Cheapest15Percent was returning NULL when the number of rows for a particular item were <=6 (6*0.15 being < 1). I was able to resolve this by adding an IF(ISNULL()) to that column, and if it was null, simply returning price/quantity instead. MUCH appreciation for your answer!